# How do you do the Dimebag Squeal?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique

I have heard that the Dimebag Squeal can be done only on Floyd Rose, though I haven't tried on a regular one though.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you need a tremolo of some sort; play a note, depress the tremolo (this will slacken the strings); catch the nearest natural harmonic, pull back on the tremolo, distortion and reverb will help you get the Dime sound.

Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TpYcA9bSaU) from the man himself